# My own Java package as Maven project on GitHub

Tags: java, maven, github

First of all: I am very new in dealing with Maven. So please look up my questions, if they are stupid.

I have the following situation: I have created a few java classes and would like to check them in as package at GitHub in one of my repositories. How that works, I know. I have already created several repos.
However, this time I would like to include my package as a dependency in one of my other projects. It should be a kind of external library.
And now I don't know how to do this.

I've already created a Maven project for my Java classes (in eclipse) and the pom.xml is done too.
I also know how to use "mvn install" to deploy my package to a local repo.
But: What exactly do I have to commit now? The src folder, maybe the target folder, the pom.xml or only the JAR file?
I'm not sure about the process. How does Maven know what needs to be loaded later when the dependency is resolved and from where?

And then, of course, my group ID must be unique on the entire GitHub platform so that Maven can address the right project. Is that correct? Is it possible to check somewhere that the group ID has already been assigned elsewhere?

Comment: I know you have to add the entry for a site like maven.org just search on google